# Is it common to use -in the integration- in this case?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, understanding

can you please tell me if this sentence is understanable to native speaker and is it common to say it like this?

> Besides being used as a stand-alone module, (the module's name) can work **in the integration** with our module.

Comment: What is the source of the sentence? Did you write it yourself? What is the relationship between the ***module (being used as a stand-alone module)*** and ***our module***?

Comment: Most of the time, choosing whether to use an article depends a great deal on context.  It would help if you could include some of the surrounding context.  That way people will be able to figure out whether an article is appropriate :-)

Comment: One English language enthusiast [believes that **in the integration** could actually be felicitous](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25718336#25718336). I could not persuade him to post his own answer though. (0:

Answer (score 5):

"**In integration**" seems not very felicitous (P.S. although it could be; I'm not sure).

I would say

> Besides being used as a stand-alone module, (the module's name) can work **in combination** with our module.

I've just googled up another possible expression:

> Besides being used as a stand-alone module, (the module's name) can work **in conjunction** with our module.

Or, per Riley Francisco's comment below,

> Besides being used as a stand-alone module, (the module's name) *can be used* **in conjunction** with our module.

---

(I'm not a native speaker, wait for more answers)

Comment: You never know if you can or can't use ***the*** before those words without any context.

Comment: @Rathony - agreed. That's why I used the word **here**: in this particular context. I'll stress this point further now. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Great answer, I was just about to write my answer when you used **in conjunction** and **in combination**. Well done.

Comment: You could also say " ...can be used **in conjunction with** our module."

Comment: No, I mean the word ***combination*** could be repeated in any context. In the combination with/In combination with are both broadly used.

Comment: @Rathony - I've deleted my note on article usage.

Comment: I think it is always better to identify the source of the sentence (who wrote it? what is the link?, etc.) before posting any answer. It is very tricky when handling such nouns as they are heavily context-dependent. If it had been written by the OP, the question should be considered as ***proof-reading request*** IMHO. At least the OP must explain where/how the sentence would be used in what circumstances.

Comment: @Rathony - I would pigeonhole it as "phrase-request", since it relates to the use of a particular phrase. We should give posters some wiggle room. (0: Not every English learner can phrase exactly what they need, and coming up with a rough sentence to illustrate the use of a necessary phrase is not that bad, IMHO.

Comment: I understand your point. I posted a comment. Let's see how the OP responds to it. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you all for commenting, I’m talking about technical terms that’s why I would like to use -integration-. I’ve googled it and it has more than million findings and it is for the IT sector. Considering the doubts about the article usage, I’m still struggling with it (because my language doesn't have articles at all) :). When I use 'the' in this sentence, it was to point out that it can be used in this special kind of integration between the two modules (just these two).

Comment: @Nina - then do wait for some other answers. You could also beef up your question with more context, per Snailboat's suggestion. (0: Articles are hard for me too as a Russian speaker, they led me to this site in the first place.

Comment: Now we are back to the square one as I predicted exactly.

Comment: @Nina I posted my answer. I don't think you need to stick to ***the integration***. You can express what you want with ***integrating*** without having to worry about the article.

Answer (score 2):

How about *module A is (fully) **compatible with** module B*?

Comment: Probably too clear for technical writers to use... ;)

Comment: Nothing improves the quality of a technical paper better than a pinch of ambiguity ;)